# Wildly looking spectrogram

Tags: python, deep-learning, scipy, data-science

I am trying to predict seizure using a spectrogram and CNN. I have 5 patient data (not much) to work with and have so gotten a validation acc around 65% = low.

When i generate a spectrogram for two different patients seizure data they look wildly different.

Filters and db conversion:

```
def nanpow2db(y):
    if isinstance(y, int) or isinstance(y, float):
        if y == 0:
            return np.nan
        else:
            ydB = 10 * np.log10(y)
    else:
        if isinstance(y, list):  # if list, turn into array
            y = np.asarray(y)
        y = y.astype(float)  # make sure it's a float array so we can put nans in it
        y[y == 0] = np.nan
        ydB = 10 * np.log10(y)

    return ydB

def butter_highpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='high', analog=False)
    y = signal.lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    b, a = signal.butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    y = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data)
    return y

def butter_bandstop_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    i, u = signal.butter(order, [low, high], btype='bandstop')
    y = signal.lfilter(i, u, data)
    return y

def apply_filter(series, FREQ):
    series = butter_bandstop_filter(series, 97, 103, FREQ, order=6)
    series = butter_bandstop_filter(series, 47, 53, FREQ, order=6)
    series = butter_highpass_filter(series, 1, FREQ, order=6)
    return series
```

The sampling rate is 500 Hz and i've split the data into windows of 4 seconds = 2000 samples of data. Hereafter i create the spectrograms.

```
def spec_save_to_folder(index, win, channel, patient_state, patient, save_path, plot_title = False, FREQ = 500):
    '''
    plotting and saving spectrogram in comprehension.
    '''
    interval = int(FREQ)   # ... the interval size,
    overlap = int(interval/2)  # ... and the overlap of interval
    series = win[0]
    time_of_observation = win[1]

    try:
        series = np.array(series).astype(np.float)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"error: {e}")
        print(f"patient_state: {patient_state} channel: {channel} index: {index} window: {series}")
    
    if plot_title:
        plt.title(f"{channel} : is_seizure = {patient_state} : {time_of_observation}")

    filt_series = apply_filter(series, FREQ)

    f, t, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(np.array(filt_series), fs=FREQ, noverlap=overlap, nfft=500, window='hann')
    Sxx = nanpow2db(Sxx)
    #normalize_color= colors.LogNorm(vmin=np.amin(Sxx), vmax=np.amax(Sxx))      
    plt.pcolormesh(t, f, Sxx, cmap='jet')
    noverlap=overlap)
    plt.show()
```

[image: More right looking spectrogram]

[image: Noisy spectrogram]

Am i missing or is this right? or do i need more filtering?

Comment: Are you using the same normalization for both plots? It's worth noting that [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html) rescales your data so that the highest value and lowest value are on a scale from [0, 1], then does the color mapping, meaning that a single very high value or very low value can drastically change the look of the whole plot.

Comment: Hi Nick, yes im using the same configuration for both plots. I was just wondering why this happens. I have a 2 channel EEG and on the second channel some of them looks normal like in the first plot and second half looks very noisy. How would you go about it ? Is it possible to rescale same for all pcolormeshj

Comment: Yes, look into the norm parameter of [pcolormesh](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolormesh.html).

Comment: Hi Nick a follow up question if i may... If i have a raw signal do i find the global min/max of the entire signal or do i convert to a decibel scale and then calculate min/max and pass those values to norm argument? because i reformat the Sxx (power spectrum) to decibel in the above code for each window ?